# MLE - CDF vs PDF as the likelihood-function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

Would maximum-likelihood estimation: with the cumulative-distribution function as the likelihood-function and the probability-density function as the likelihood-function, yield the same/equal estimates?

- If NO, then which likelihood function would yield better estimate? (since, [CDF can be a likelihood-function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560668/mle-cdf-vs-pdf-as-the-likelihood-function#560670))

**My thoughts**: *I don't think they will be equal* $\rightarrow$ consider two probability density-functions $f_{X}(x;\hat\theta_1)$ and $f_{X}(x;\hat\theta_2)$, such that $f_{X}(x;\hat\theta_2) = f_{X}(x+b;\hat\theta_1)$. Let the density-functions be concave, and Let $x_1$ be the point-of-maxima for $f_{X}(x;\theta_1)$ [so, $f_{X}(x;\theta_2)$ will be maximum at $x_1 - b$], and also the observed-sample. If $F_{X}$ denotes the CDF of $f_{X}$ (for any $\theta \in \Theta$), then

- With $f_{X}(x;\theta)$ as the likelihood-function, we get
  $$
  \underset{\theta\,\in\,\Theta}{\mathrm{arg\,\,max}}\bigl\{f_{X}(x_1;\theta)\bigr\} = \hat\theta_{1}
  $$
- With $F_{X}(x;\theta)$ as the likelihood-function, we get
  $$
  \underset{\theta\,\in\,\Theta}{\mathrm{arg\,\,max}}\bigl\{F_{X}(x_1;\theta)\bigr\} = \hat\theta_{2}
  $$

**PS**: Other similar questions

- [How do I determine the appropriate likelihood function for a custom CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/544104/248568)
- [Can you calculate the MLE of a CDF?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/502549/248568)

Comment: Doesn't https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248476 answer your questions?

Comment: @whuber - to be honest, I'm still working my way through "fundamentals of statistics" and it will take me a while before I can fully appreciate the answers to [that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/248476/248568) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CDF can be used in the likelihood. Remember that the likelihood encodes the information about our observations.

For one example, if the observation is not known exactly but bounded from below, like in survival analysis, then we represent this information with a CDF in the likelihood. See section 2 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/vignettes/flexsurv.pdf

Comment: Okay! I think I should re-frame the question: would the maximum-likelihood estimates be equal - with CDF as the likelihood and PDF as the likelihood? (assume we can derive both function) **PS**: I have re-framed the main question/post.

Comment: The answer to your new question is no, because the likelihoods are not the same (i.e. they represent different information about the observations), so there is no reason for the maximizing parameters to be equal.

Comment: In the simplest case, compare the two likelihoods interpretations: $f(x; \theta)$ represents "I saw an observation $x$ from dist $f$", vs  $F(x; \theta)$ represents "I saw an observation _that was less than $x$_ from dist $f$". The former has more information, so you could get more accurate estimates.

Comment: I suspect this may confuse the issue.  If you observe $x_1,\ldots x_n$ from your sample, you are not going to use the CDF as a likelihood.  It is when your observation  is say that $k_1$ of your sample of $n$ are less than or equal to $x_1$  and $k_2$ are less than or equal to $x_2$  that you might use the  CDF.

Comment: @Henry does $x_1$ need to be different than $x_2$ though? A dataset could look like $[10^*, 10^*, 10^*, 10^*]$, where $*$ denotes a right-censored point. In that case, the likelihood is only made up of CDFs. If you agree, then I'm afraid I am not understanding your comment.